# Improvement in vote-to-close: More context information for reviewers

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

Processing close vote reviews is too time-consuming for the reviewer, as you can see in the not decreasing count of close-review-items.

Consequently, we should give the reviewer as much information for the current case as possible, to speed up his or her decision:

My feature request to achieve this would be (in gherkin language):

- **In order to** speed up processing review of close votes
- **As a** close/leave-open/reopen-vote-reviewer
- **I want to** see the reasons why the previous reviewers thought it is a good or bad idea to close a post
- **And I want to** have the opportunity to leave a comment to other close/leave-open/reopen-vote-reviewers

So instead of inventing a reason to close/leave open I can simply agree or disagree with the previous votes.

Todos:

- Every close/leave-open/reopen-vote should have an optional comment field for the voter to add information for the other voters that follow up.
- If I review a close/leave-open/reopen-vote for an article I want to see all close/leave-open/reopen-votes for that article with type and comment plus an upvote/downvote arrow for the previous votes.

Comment: I'm... *Intrigued* by this idea - in particular the notion of leaving reasons for *not* closing - but I'd like to see more details on how you think it would fit into the existing UI without *further* bogging down the process.

Comment: But this makes clicking through harder!

Answer (score 9):

I agree that the close review queue is perhaps more time consuming than some of the others and that is probably contributing to its size.

However, I don't think either of your proposed solutions is a good idea as that will basically encourage reviewers to *herd-vote* (something which I think is already a bit of a problem) instead of independently reviewing the question on its own merits.

Comment: i agree the "herd vote" can be problematic but if there is pro-close-comment and a contra-close-comment i prefer having a "herd vote" over not reducing the "close vote" pile at all. Since voting is only allowed to experienced users with high reputation i hope that "herd voting" is not a big problem. In my opinion stackoverflow is a great question/answer side because of its easy up/down-voting machanism. answers with high upvotes are most likely to be correct. why not use this powerfull feature to process close votes

Comment: @k3b Unfortunately I think that herd-voting is indeed a problem even with users who have higher reputations and aught to know better (just take a look at the number of posts complaining about robo-reviewers and the like).